# PySimpleGUI : После повторного включения видимости элемента, он не встаёт на своё место

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

Элемент под цифрой 3 почему-то переходит на новую строку, если ему сначала отключить, а потом включить видимость... Не могу найти причину.[image: После включения видимости]
[image: До отключения видимости]

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def WTF_2():
    window.Element("1").Update('1', visible=False)  
    window.Element("2").Update('2', visible=False)
    window.Element("3").Update('3', visible=False)


def WTF_1():
    window.Element("1").Update('1', visible=True) 
    window.Element("2").Update('2', visible=True)
    window.Element("3").Update('3', visible=True)


layout = [
    [sg.InputText("0", justification="center", key='0', size=(10, 1)),
     sg.InputText("1", justification="center", key='1', size=(10, 1))
     ],
    [
     sg.InputText("2", justification="center", key='2', size=(10, 1)),
     sg.InputText("3", justification="center", key='3', size=(10, 1))
     ],
    [sg.Button('WTF_1', key='WTF_1'), sg.Button('WTF_2', key='WTF_2')]
]
window = sg.Window('000', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=1)
    if event == 'Exit' or event == 'Cancel' or event == 'Отмена' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        print('Good Bye!')
        window.close()
        break
    elif event == "WTF_1":
        WTF_1()
    elif event == "WTF_2":
        WTF_2()
```

Проблема пропадает, если оставить нижний элемент неизменяемым, но можно ли как-то без этого обойтись?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как ты располагаешь их так

```
layout = [
    [sg.InputText("0", justification="center", key='0', size=(10, 1)),
     sg.InputText("1", justification="center", key='1', size=(10, 1))
     ],
    [
     sg.InputText("2", justification="center", key='2', size=(10, 1)),
     sg.InputText("3", justification="center", key='3', size=(10, 1))
     ]
```

он будет иногда их группировать в столбец. Лучше делать так

```
layout = [
    [sg.InputText("0", justification="center", key='0', size=(10, 1)), sg.InputText("1", justification="center", key='1', size=(10, 1))],
    [sg.InputText("2", justification="center", key='2', size=(10, 1)), sg.InputText("3", justification="center", key='3', size=(10, 1))]
     ]
```

Comment: Это случаеться из-за переноса строки

Comment: Спасибо за совет.
Не "случаеться", а "случается". 
:)

Answer (score 2):

Короче, решил проблему, засунув каждый элемент в столбец.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def WTF_2():
    window.Element("1").Update('1', visible=False)
    window.Element("2").Update('2', visible=False)
    window.Element("3").Update('3', visible=False)


def WTF_1():
    window.Element("1").Update('1', visible=True)
    window.Element("2").Update('2', visible=True)
    window.Element("3").Update('3', visible=True)


col1 = [[sg.InputText("0", justification="center", key='0', size=(10, 1))]]
col2 = [[sg.InputText("1", justification="center", key='1', size=(10, 1))]]
col3 = [[sg.InputText("2", justification="center", key='2', size=(10, 1))]]
col4 = [[sg.InputText("3", justification="center", key='3', size=(10, 1))]]

layout = [
    [sg.Column(col1), sg.Column(col2)], [sg.Column(col3), sg.Column(col4)],

    [sg.Button('WTF_1', key='WTF_1'), sg.Button('WTF_2', key='WTF_2')]
]
window = sg.Window('000', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=1)
    if event == 'Exit' or event == 'Cancel' or event == 'Отмена' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        print('Good Bye!')
        window.close()
        break
    elif event == "WTF_1":
        WTF_1()
    elif event == "WTF_2":
        WTF_2()
```